# How do I solve a problem with image path for carousel

Tags: html, reactjs, reactstrap

I have an image folder named "images" in public and a fold named component in src. I tried to define the path to the images but none is displaying.

I have tried to reference to the path as illustrated below.

```
const items = [
  {
    src: '/public/images/fraction-slider/fraction_6.png',
    altText: 'Slide 1',
    caption: 'Slide 1'
  },
  {
    src: '/public/images/fraction-slider/fraction_2.png',
    altText: 'Slide 2',
    caption: 'Slide 2'
  },
  {
    src: '/public/images/fraction-slider/build.png',
    altText: 'Slide 3',
    caption: 'Slide 3'
  }
];
```

I expect the images to display

Comment: `/public` will be valuable when the react code will be built

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it by removing "/public", so i have "./images/fraction-slider/ .png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/public` will be valuable when the react code will be built.

So please try to remove it while developing

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, sorry for bothering you all. I have later fixed the problem with src: './images

```
const items = [
  {
    src: './images/fraction-slider/fraction_6.png',
    altText: 'Slide 1',
    caption: 'Slide 1'
  },
  {
    src: './images/fraction-slider/fraction_2.png',
    altText: 'Slide 2',
    caption: 'Slide 2'
  },
  {
    src: './images/fraction-slider/build.png',
    altText: 'Slide 3',
    caption: 'Slide 3'
  }
];
```